# Game crash due to Leadbolt ads implementation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, ads, leadbolt

I have integrated Leadbolt ads in my Unity3D android game. But, whenever I try to start my application, it crashes and when I give it a try with switching off the internet access, it works fine. So, this means that ads are creating some problem.

Below is my ads requesting C# code.

```
// Initialize Leadbolt SDK with your API Key
AppTrackerAndroid.startSession("****YOUR API KEY****");

// cache Leadbolt Ad without showing it
AppTrackerAndroid.loadModuleToCache("inapp");

//Requesting LeadBolt Ads
if (AppTrackerAndroid.isAdReady("inapp"))
{
    AppTrackerAndroid.loadModule("inapp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Leadbolt's Unity package? You can find it in the Help section, it's called "Using Unity Android".  You can also contact your Leadbolt Account Manager who will identify the issue and provide support.

If you email Leadbolt with more info, we will get back to you ASAP with help:
1. What version of framework you are using?
2. What version of our SDK you are using?
3. Have you used the sample app as provided, compiled/build this and ran it on a mobile device?
4. Have you compiled/built the sample app with your provided API key (besides your app in the Portal) and seen whether the ads appear fine?